# Typescript ReferenceError: Namespace is not defined

Tags: typescript, referenceerror

I have declared a global namespace in a typings.d.ts file like this:

```
declare namespace NAMESPACE {
  export enum Colours {
    GREEN = 'GREEN',
    AMBER = 'AMBER',
    RED = 'RED',
  }
}
```

My tsconfig looks like this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx"
  },
  "include": [
    "src",
    "./global.d.ts",
    "./typings.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

When I'm trying to access the enum I defined in my namespace

Ex.

```
if (scoreColour === NAMESPACE.Colours.GREEN)) {...}
```

I'm getting a runtime error saying: Typescript ReferenceError: Namespace is not defined.

Do you have any idea how to solve this?

Thank you

Comment: My guess is it’s not truly global and you have to import it?  Maybe something on this docs page helps: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces.html

Comment: The thing I can't understand is that I have some other types exported in this namespace and that's working. It looks like the issue applies just when I'm trying to access enums.

Comment: Ok so when you write a TS code it gets compiled into the JS part and the .d.ts declarations, right?  Types, interfaces, etc are removed from the JS and and only exist in the .d.ts.  Similarly to classes, enums have both a JS part and a .d.ts part.  You are using your enum as a variable here, but if it exists only in a declaration then there is no variable in the JS.  You have the declaration but you are missing the implementation.

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces-and-modules.html#needless-namespacing -  this link helped me solve this problem, try this once